# Thinkpad T420 upper UltraNav keys are not working

Tags: mouse, touchpad, thinkpad

I have an issue with an T420.
Using the Trackpoint the higher keys are easier to reach, but not working.
Only the lower ones respond to clicks, the one with an red circle are not responding.

[image: UltraNav Keys]

I Googled and scanned StackExchange but could find any solution so far.

What I tried so far:
- Reinstalling the UltraNav Driver
- Changing the Settings (s. UltraNav settings)

[image: Settings]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into the firmware (BIOS/EFI) and check if the TrackPoint is enabled. If this is true, boot a regular GNU/Linux (for this purpose I recommend a live image of Fedora) and check if it works with it.

If that doesn't work I'am afraid your ThinkPad has a hardware problem. In the worst case your mainboard  is defect or your keys inside the Palmrest. If you are lucky, just the cable is loose. The TrackPoint is a part of the keyboard, the TouchPad and all buttons around it have an own cable on the PS/2-BUS.

Comment: How? If I just boot and try they are not working like in Windows. I used Ubuntu.

Comment: That indicates a hardware related problem. You could download the hardware "maintenance manual" and disamble the Palmrest and check the cables.

Comment: Fu... so [page 77](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t420_t420i_hmm.pdf) only shows one cable. Do you think readjusting this one could help or should I live with the problem?

Comment: If you are good craftsman you could give it a try. That is your own decission.

Comment: Do you know where I should look? Clean up the pins is enough or do I have to solder? I can handle some crafts but I'm not an electrical engineer.

Comment: Just trail and error :-)

Comment: Oh ok, at the end I will destroy more than cure ;) I try

Comment: The rest of the TouchPad works? Pointer and all?